# How to get my link to display as a link from my laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to send an error message with a link. The issue I'm having is that when I get the error I get the html version of my link
EG: `Please go to <a href="http://laravel.test/admin/products/160">product</a>`

What I would like is for my error message to say `Please go to product` where as product would be a link.

Here is my code

```
public function updateProduct(Product $product)
{
    if(!empty($product->status))
    {
        $url = "<a href=".route('product.show', $product->id).">Product</a>";
        return redirect()->route('product.index', [$product])->with('error', "Go to $url.");
    }
}
```

and in my index.blade.php

I have this

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        @foreach($products as $product)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $product->name }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@push('js')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @if(session('error'))
            Swal.fire('Error!', '{{ session('error') }}', 'error');
        @endif
    </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are sending html as response. you have to use [{!! !!}](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data) to print that response as your expectation.

```
@push('js')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @if (session('error'))
            Swal.fire('Error!', '{!! session('error') !!}', 'error');
        @endif
    </script>
@endpush
```

this will show the swal as *Go to [Product](https://#)*

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about `{!! !!}` thank you so much